# (My)SQL Iteratively using data from one table to fill another /select from lists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two (My)SQL tables A, B.  A has many columns A.(a,b,c,d...). B contains only two columns x,y. The number of rows in B is (much) less than that in A. All values in B.x are unique.

A is fully populated. In B only the values in B.x exist, B.y is empty and I want to fill B.y with the values from (say) A.b, corresponding to each value of B.x which appear as A.a

In other words, what I need to do is for each B.x find the match in A.a and take the corresponding A.b and insert it into B.y in the row containing the value of B.x. I then need to iterate this over all the values in B.x.

For reasons that we don't need to go into I need to do this in a single SQL statement; no PHP, no Python, etc. No embedding. What I am looking for is a way of making an iterated selection from one into the other. I also want to avoid the creation of temporary tables.

FWIW I can't make any assumptions about the number of rows in each table.

Hope that this is clear enough. Thanks for any help that you are able to give.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes A.a values are also unique. If they are not you may need to look at a way of grouping them.

```
update B inner join A on B.x=A.a set B.y=A.b;
```

Comment: This works!...needed a bit of tinkering but that's my DB and nothing that I put in the question, certainly nothing that you could have known. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to normalize your A table, if for each A.a value the value of A.b is unique the following query shall work

```
update B
   set B.y =
       (select distinct A.b
          from A
         where A.a = B.x)
```

Comment: Returned Error Code 1242 - though I thought that it would work :-(